# I am having difficulty understanting this question from thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, gas

[image: Question 15.7]

According to above question the process is isothermal. Hence the product PV is always constant. Since Volume is decreasing, hence Pressure must increase. Hence Work done by gas is calculated by integral of P.dV(pressure is not constant, always changing at every instant) . According to me, final answer must be **negative of option (4)** [because Work done by gas will be negative of Work done by atmosphere because it is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction]  but **given option is (1)**. Please tell me where I went wrong in understanding this question.

Comment: Are you saying the so called correct answer is (1)?

Comment: Also, which version of the first law is used for this question, is it $\Delta U=Q-W$ or is it $\Delta U=Q+W$?

Comment: @BobD Yes according to answer key correct option is 1. And both formulae are correct, ΔU=Q−W  is generally used in physics, whereas ΔU=Q+W is used in chemistry. This change in sign arises due different sign conventions used but final answer will always be same.

Comment: I agree the answer should be option 4, but the sign will depend on which version of the first law is used.

Comment: @BobD  ΔU=Q−W must be used here since this question is from physics POV.

Comment: Wait a minute. I think I see the problem here. The answer is option 1.

Comment: please explain, this question has bugged me whole day @BobD

Comment: I will post some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to me, final answer must be negative of option (4)

This is a tricky question.

If they wanted to know the total work done on the gas, option 4  would apply based on the first law version $\Delta U=Q-W$. But they are only asking for the work done by the atmosphere. That pressure is constant.

From here you should be able to determine the correct answer (we can not provide complete solutions to H&E type questions).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I know where my thinking went wrong... @BobD